# How does weapon damage work?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I have noticed that in the multiplayer, the weapon customization meters are not reliable. For instance the harrier rifle on level one has a decent amount of damage per second when the weapon customization chart would indicate otherwise. Is there a way of actually quantifying the damage like the powers. Is there an online source like a wiki that has this information?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wiki page, check under the Weapon Types category. These are more or less reliable: http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons#Mass_Effect_3

http://masseffect.wikia.com/ is a rather useful site anyway, most ME-related answers can be found there.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Right, but the answer is a relatively large table of statistics across multiple pages, so I thought this way it's more optimal. Thank you for the heads up, anyway! (And strictly speaking, the link was the answer: "Is there an online source like a wiki that has this information?")

Comment: Another site I like to use to work out a good build is this one: http://narida.pytalhost.com/me3/classes/#00BAAAAB0@0HAC@  it shows you exactly how much damage you'll do for each power/gun if you spec a certain way.